# Cannot resolve NoReverseMatch at / error in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make an auction website (for a project). And we need to have an option to add each product to the "watchlist". However, I keep getting error when clicking on "watchlist" button. This is in Python using Django.

This is the exact error I'm getting:

**NoReverseMatch at /viewlisting/3/addwatchlist
Reverse for 'addwatchlist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['viewlisting/(?P<listing_id>[0-9]+)/addwatchlist$']**

Here is a summary of my code:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create_listing", views.create_listing, name="create_listing"),
    path("viewlisting/<int:listing_id>", views.viewlisting, name="viewlisting"),
    path("viewlisting/<int:listing_id>/addwatchlist", views.addwatchlist, name="addwatchlist")
]
```

views.py:

```
def viewlisting(request,listing_id):
    productname= listings.objects.get(id=listing_id)
    name= productname.name
    description = productname.description
    image = productname.image
    price= productname.price
    seller = productname.seller
    category = productname.category
    date = productname.date
    productid= productname.id


  
    return render(request, "auctions/viewlisting.html",{
        "name":name,
        "description":description,
        "image":image,
        "price":price,
        "seller":seller,
        "category":category,
        "date":date,
        "id":productid
    })


def addwatchlist(request,listing_id):

    if request.method == "POST":

        item_exists= watchlist.objects.filter(
            id = listing_id, user= request.user.username
        )

        if item_exists:
            show_watchlist = watchlist.objects.all()
            exist_alert= "This item already exists in your watchlist!"
            return render(request,"auctions/viewlisting.html",{
                "alert":exist_alert,
                "show_watchlist":show_watchlist
            })
        else:
            new_item = watchlist()
            new_item.user = request.user.username
            new_item.listing = listings.objects.get(id=listing_id).name
            new_item.save()
            success_alert = "This item was added to your watchlist!"

            
            show_watchlist = watchlist.objects.all()
            return render(request,"auctions/viewlisting.html",{
              "alert":  success_alert,
              "show_watchlist":show_watchlist,
            })
    else:
        return render(request,"auctions/viewlisting.html")
```

And this is my viewlisting html page which renders different product detials and allows the user to add the product to their watchlist.

viewlisting.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body%}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src={{image}} style="max-width: 350px;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><strong>{{ name }}</strong><br> {{description}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <strong>Current Price:</strong>    <sup>CAD$</sup>{{price}}
            <br>
            <strong>Category:</strong> {{ category }}
            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="{% url 'addwatchlist' id %}" method="POST"> 
                {% csrf_token %}
               <button  style="color:ghostwhite" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> 
                Add to Watchlist 
               </button>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{alert}}</h5> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>   
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h6>Your Watchlist:</h6>
                    {% for i in show_watchlist %}
                    <li>{{i.listing}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

And this is models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

    def __str__ (self):
        return f"username:{self.username}, email:{self.email}, password:{self.password}"

class listings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null= True, unique=True)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(null= True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image= models.URLField()

    def __str__ (self):
        return f"{self.name} by {self.seller}: {self.price}, {self.category}, {self.date}, {self.description}, {self.date}, {self.image} "

class bids(models.Model):

    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="bidder", null=True)
    bid_price = models.IntegerField(null= True) 
    product= models.ForeignKey(listings, on_delete= models.CASCADE, to_field= "name", null=True)
    bid_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bidder} bid {self.bid_price} on {self.product}: posted on {self.bid_date}"


class comments(models.Model):
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="commenter", null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(listings, on_delete= models.CASCADE, to_field= "name",null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.commenter} commented {self.content} on listing: {self.listing} ({self.post_date})"



class watchlist(models.Model):
    user=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    listing = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str(self):
        return f"User: {self.user}, Product: {self.listing}"
```

I would really appreciate any help or hints.
Also, let me know if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing `id` in form url and `listing_id` in urls.py

change `<form action="{% url 'addwatchlist' id %}" method="POST">` to `<form action="{% url 'addwatchlist' listing_id=id %}" method="POST">`

Comment: I just tried that ,but it still is giving me an error -->

**NoReverseMatch at /viewlisting/2/addwatchlist
Reverse for 'addwatchlist' with keyword arguments '{'listing_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['viewlisting/(?P<listing_id>[0-9]+)/addwatchlist$']**